# Show maps on android emulator - google play services out of date

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-play

I want to show Google Maps on my emulator.
I'm using API 17 and installed gsm.APK & vending.APK

The emulator tells me I need to update the google services.
When I push update it go to google play and do nothing.

I also get this warning on LogCat

google play services out of date requires 4242000 but found 4131530

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you cannot run Google maps on the built-in emulator.  They just don't work.  You need to test your app on either a device or a 3rd party emulator.

For my needs, I'm a huge fan of the [Genymotion device-specific emulators](http://www.genymotion.com/)